# Getting minimum possible number after performing operations on array elements

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic-programming

Question : Given an integer(n) denoting the no. of particles initially
Given an array of sizes of these particles
These particles can go into any number of simulations (possibly none)
In one simualtion two particles combines to give another particle with size as the difference between the size of them (possibly 0).
Find the smallest particle that can be formed.

```
constraints         
n<=1000        
size<=1e9   

Example 1    
3       
30 10 8            
Output           
2         
Explaination- 10 - 8 is the smallest we can achive

Example 2         
4        
1 2 4 8           
output            
1           
explanation            
We cannot make another 1 so as to get 0 so smallest without any simulation is 1

example 3         
5         
30 27 26 10 6         
output
0          
30-26=4            
10-6 =4          
4-4 =0
```

My thinking: I can only think of the brute force solution which will obviously time out. Can anyone help me out here with just the approach? I think it's related to dynamic programming

Comment: What is the time constraint?

Comment: @Happypig375 O(N^2) will be optimal

Comment: @Saqlain  Think about using a priority queue.

Comment: @vivek_23 I thought about priority queue and applying the operation on 2 greatest elements each time but it fails on some cases like example 3 I have given)

Comment: @Saqlain In 3rd example, `27` was never used?

Comment: @vivek_23 No. It is not necessary to use all the numbers.

Comment: @Saqlain Ok. Can you provide a link to the problem?

Comment: @vivek_23 I found it here: https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/334981/Hackwithinfy-or-Online-Assesment-or-Antimatter-Particles

Comment: @Saqlain We can still apply a priority queue repeatedly but time complexity would go high. Also, it's kinda unclear if we can reuse the same element for 2 pairs of numbers. I would rather advice to not take unclear or at least not testable questions too seriously.

Comment: @vivek_23 Thank you. can you give an example how to use priority queue in the 3rd example?
Also I know myself, this question was asked in last year hackwithinfy. I'm preparing for that.
If it's still unclear to you: In one simulation, you can choose 2 elements Ai and Aj, delete these elements from the array and add the element |Ai - Aj| to the array

Comment: @Saqlain PQ would have all the O(n^2) differences possible. We would then repeatedly do it until our PQ becomes empty. However, this adds Ai and Aj difference and also Ai and Ak difference. Not sure if this is a legal move.

Comment: @vivek_23 Why are we using the PQ on the differences ? How are you sure that it's correct? and Why not use it directly on the original array instead?

Comment: @Saqlain It's starts with original array. We get O(n^2) differences. Now, we do this repeatedly on the current level data set and we get next set which has O(n^2 - 1) values. Likewise, we do this until we empty the queue. But this doesn't look like a feasible solution considering the time overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be solved in `O(n^2log(n))`

Consider your third example: `30 27 26 10 6`

Sort the input to make it : `6 10 26 27 30`

Build a list of differences for each `(i,j)` combination.

For:

`i = 1 -> 4 20 21 24`

`i = 2 -> 16, 17, 20`

`i = 3 -> 1, 4`

`i = 4 -> 3`

There is no list for `i = 5` why? because it is already considered for combination with other particles before.

Now consider the below cases:

***Case 1***

The particle `i` is not combined with any other particle yet. This means some other particle should have been combined with a particle other than `i`.
This suggests us that we need to search for `A[i]` in the lists `j = 1 to N` except for `j = i`.
Get the nearest value. This can be done using binary search. Because your difference lists are sorted! Then your result for now is `|A[i] - NearestValueFound|`

***Case 2***

The particle `i` is combined with some other particle.
Take example `i = 1` above and lets consider that its combined with particle `2`. The result is `4`. 
So search for `4` in all the lists except list `2` - because we consider that particle `2` is already combined with particle `1` and we shouldn't search list `2`.
Do we have a best match? It seems we have a match `4` found in the list `3`. It needn't be `0` - in this case it is `0` so just return `0`.

Repeat Case 1, 2 for all particles. Time complexity is `O(n^2log(n))`, because you are doing a binary search on all lists for each `i` except the list `i`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools as it

N = int(input())

nums = list()

for i in range(N):
    nums.append(int(input()))

_min = min(nums)

def go(li):
    global _min
    if len(li)>1:
        for i in it.combinations(li, 2):
            temp = abs(i[0] - i[1])
            if _min > temp:
                _min = temp
            k = li.copy()
            k.remove(i[0])
            k.remove(i[1])
            k.append(temp)
            go(k)

go(nums)

print(_min)
```